# Java Getting all possible combinations from only one item per key

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, permutation, guava

I'm trying to get all possibilities from a `Map<String,List<String>>`.
I want to get only one item per key, ex:

```
 Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("first", asList("first1", "first2", "first3"));
    map.put("second", asList("second1", "second2", "second3"));
    map.put("anyOther", asList("anyType1", "anyType2", "anyType3"));
```

I want one item per key and get all possible values from other keys, ex:

```
first1;second1;anytype1
first1;second2;anytype2
first1;second3;anytype3
first1;second1;anytype1
first1;second2;anytype3
first1;second3;anytype2
.....
```

Do you guys have any Idea How should I do that? I can change my data structure, maybe use a POJO or something like that.

Comment: How would you select which permutations you want? If you only want `first1;...` why have `first2` etc. in the first place? And why don't you want to get `first1;second3;anytype1` etc. - and how should that get filtered out?

Comment: Hi Thomas, basically I want one item of first key for example and then, permutate it will all other items in other key's values. Not sure If I was clear. Actually, while I'm writing this comment I realize that I don't want the permutations itself, I want all possible combinations for each item with items bellow. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`Lists#cartesianProduct(List<List>)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/27.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#cartesianProduct-java.util.List-):

```
final List<List<String>> product = 
    Lists.cartesianProduct(ImmutableList.copyOf(map.values()));
System.out.println(product);
// prints: [[anyType1, first1, second1], [anyType1, first1, second2], [anyType1, first1, second3], [anyType1, first2, second1], [anyType1, first2, second2], [anyType1, first2, second3], [anyType1, first3, second1], [anyType1, first3, second2], [anyType1, first3, second3], [anyType2, first1, second1], [anyType2, first1, second2], [anyType2, first1, second3], [anyType2, first2, second1], [anyType2, first2, second2], [anyType2, first2, second3], [anyType2, first3, second1], [anyType2, first3, second2], [anyType2, first3, second3], [anyType3, first1, second1], [anyType3, first1, second2], [anyType3, first1, second3], [anyType3, first2, second1], [anyType3, first2, second2], [anyType3, first2, second3], [anyType3, first3, second1], [anyType3, first3, second2], [anyType3, first3, second3]]
```